# Get json substring using a particular object node name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I have a json string like this. Its a part of my json string.

```
                                "foldChildren": "false",
                                "branchColor": "#000000",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "3f67cbab-ff5a-4f61-b1ef-d551271e8af2",
                                        "parentId": "211c838e-3e2d-4919-ab09-dd7f8a901b97",
                                        "text": {
                                            "caption": "f",
                                            "font": {
                                                "style": "normal",
                                                "weight": "normal",
                                                "decoration": "none",
                                                "size": "15",
                                                "color": "#000000"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "offset": {
                                            "x": "30",
                                            "y": "93"
                                        },
                                        "foldChildren": "false",
                                        "branchColor": "#000000",
                                        "children": {
                                            "id": "2ecaecb6-d55c-4203-bace-f14e276700af",
                                            "parentId": "3f67cbab-ff5a-4f61-b1ef-d551271e8af2",
                                            "text": {
                                                "caption": "x",
                                                "font": {
                                                    "style": "normal",
                                                    "weight": "normal",
                                                    "decoration": "none",
                                                    "size": "15",
                                                    "color": "#000000"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "offset": {
                                                "x": "122",
                                                "y": "114"
                                            },
                                            "foldChildren": "false",
                                            "branchColor": "#000000",
                                            "children": ""
                                        }
                                    },
```

- What i need is to find first node object with name "children" and get all the string inside that children object.

  Expected output from first step

  ```
  [
                              {
                                  "id": "3f67cbab-ff5a-4f61-b1ef-d551271e8af2",
                                  "parentId": "211c838e-3e2d-4919-ab09-dd7f8a901b97",
                                  "text": {
                                      "caption": "f",
                                      "font": {
                                          "style": "normal",
                                          "weight": "normal",
                                          "decoration": "none",
                                          "size": "15",
                                          "color": "#000000"
                                      }
                                  },
                                  "offset": {
                                      "x": "30",
                                      "y": "93"
                                  },
                                  "foldChildren": "false",
                                  "branchColor": "#000000",
                                  "children": {
                                      "id": "2ecaecb6-d55c-4203-bace-f14e276700af",
                                      "parentId": "3f67cbab-ff5a-4f61-b1ef-d551271e8af2",
                                      "text": {
                                          "caption": "x",
                                          "font": {
                                              "style": "normal",
                                              "weight": "normal",
                                              "decoration": "none",
                                              "size": "15",
                                              "color": "#000000"
                                          }
                                      },
                                      "offset": {
                                          "x": "122",
                                          "y": "114"
                                      },
                                      "foldChildren": "false",
                                      "branchColor": "#000000",
                                      "children": ""
                                  }
                              },
  ```
- Now I need to get next node object with name "children" from the json string got from first step.
  Expected output after second step

  ```
    {
                              "id": "2ecaecb6-d55c-4203-bace-f14e276700af",
                              "parentId": "3f67cbab-ff5a-4f61-b1ef-d551271e8af2",
                              "text": {
                                  "caption": "x",
                                  "font": {
                                      "style": "normal",
                                      "weight": "normal",
                                      "decoration": "none",
                                      "size": "15",
                                      "color": "#000000"
                                  }
                              },
                              "offset": {
                                  "x": "122",
                                  "y": "114"
                              },
                              "foldChildren": "false",
                              "branchColor": "#000000",
                              "children": ""
                          }
                      },
  ```
- and so on till the string ends.

Comment: what output you want ???

Comment: i want json sub string starting from node having name children

Comment: From above what final output you expect and in which format?

Comment: Same as input format json string

Comment: You need to loop itself to find one like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oyfnhdd0/

Comment: @cjmling thanks its giving my desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to find this "children" node on any given JSON structure, which in that case you can do a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) which will traverse your entire JSON structure.

Check out this other StackOverflow post: [How to do a recursive search of this Javascript/JSON tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465886/how-to-do-a-recursive-search-of-this-javascript-json-tree)