# Are there resources to handle Google Vision JSON output?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

The google cloud vision API works great, and produces huge complicated JSON documents. I was wondering if there are resources for handling these documents, preferably a node package that helps with searching them. I can't seem to find the resources.

The JSON files were generating using this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf

Comment: I understand that you are looking for some functionality besides the one provided by the [official Vision API node client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision)  to make the requests, so, can you explain what do you mean by "handling these documents" and "searching  them"? I'm not sure if you're looking for a library that provides JSON utilities

Comment: Imagine like `ocrResult.find('some text')` the file doesn't even parse out the words, and some of the OCR result is a little confusing with punctuation. The files seem very structured to not have any libraries officially handle them.

Comment: Got it. No, there are no official libraries that provide this functionality. I suggest to create a new feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) to the Vision API team asking for a library with the functionality desired. In the meantime,   for searches like the one you mentioned,  you can do a [recursive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465886/how-to-do-a-recursive-search-of-this-javascript-json-tree) on the JSON